# Return true if object is closer than a value. (Speherasting) in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, casting, raycasting

I have a script, for example, attached to a fire and I want to make damage to a player if he gets closer than a value to this fire.

```
public float fireDamageRange = 5;
public float fireDamage = 10;

private Vector3 origin;
private Vector3 direction;

void Update(){
    origin = transform.position;
    direction = transform.forward;

    RaycastHit fireHit;
    if (Physics.SphereCast(origin, fireDamageRange, direction, out fireHit) && fireHit.transform.gameObject.layer == LayerMask.NameToLayer("Player") && !makingDamage)
    {
        makingDamage = true;
        MakeDamage(fireHit);
        StartCoroutine(WaitToMakeDamage());
    }
}
IEnumerator WaitToMakeDamage()
{
    yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.2f);
    makingDamage = false;
}
```

The script is attached to the fire.
This only returns true if the Player is actually fireDamageRange away of the origin, not if he gets closer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there only 1 player in your game? (solo game)

Comment: @Cid yes, but all Subgameobjects of the Player also have the layer "Player"(Camera, weapon etc)

Comment: You are also interacting with the physics engine inside the `Update` method. Please change it to `FixedUpdate`.

Comment: What you're actually looking for is a 'Trigger' zone and `OnTriggerStay(...)`.  Check google or the Unity tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just calculate the distance between the player and the fire and check if it's in range

The distance can be easily calculated using [Vector3.Distance()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html)

```
public float fireDamageRange = 5;
public float fireDamage = 10;
public GameObject player; // the player

private Vector3 origin;
private Vector3 direction;

void Update(){
    float distance = Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, transform.position);
    if (distance <= fireDamageRange)
    {
        // handle damage to the player
    }
}
```